# Windows is hacked - All file's extension have changed

Tags: windows, security, malware, antivirus, antimalware

We have a Microsoft Windows server, we find all files changed to an extension `.ETH` file (Specially the AutoCAD files `.dwg` files).

As the following:

[image: Hacked Files]

All files converted to `.id-26E67253.[helpfilerestore@india.com].ETH`.

Also, If I tried to connect any flash USB to the computer, all files inside the USB Drive hacked also.

I just need any suggestion, how can I get my old files, and how can I fix the virus or hacking?

Comment: this is very likely a ransomware attack, ETH apparently means ETHereum the cryptocurrency, and the ID is needed for attacker to get your decryption key. your best bet is use various decryptor made available by antivirus vendor, like the one from [kaspersky](https://noransom.kaspersky.com/), ymmv depends on the ransomware algo

Comment: Try using https://id-ransomware.malwarehunterteam.com/ to identify the malware - if there is a way to get your files back you should get the info.

Answer (score 1):

It is a ransomware named Dharma.
Check this link [Dharma Ransomware](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-helpfilerestoreindia-com-eth/)